# EPi Server: Dynamically populate fields defined in the FileSummary.config

Tags: c#, .net, xml, episerver, episerver-6

So I found out recently that you can change the fields that defines the metadata for each file uploaded in EPi Server's File Management system, simply by editing the `FileSummary.config` file.

In this `FileSummary.config` file I can define fields statically with XForms definitions, but is it possible to dynamically populate fields with for example data from pages or defined site categories?

Edit) I see it's possible to define JavaScript in there so that might be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a control adapter to add some controls to the file summary edit /add control

You would register your adapter in the AdapterMappings.browser file as follows:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      ...
      <adapter controlType="EPiServer.UI.Hosting.EditCustomFileSummary"
               adapterType="MyLibrary.Adapters.FileSummaryAdapter, MyLibrary" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

You would then need to create a control class that derives from ControlAdapter

```
public class FileSummaryAdapter : ControlAdapter 
{
}
```

Within here you can create and add you own controls to the 'wrapped' EditCustomFileSummary, here's an example I have used previously to add a Tags control to the file summary dialog:

```
// Override the OnInit method to ensure our controls are added to the edit control
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Some code omitted for clarity
    ...

    // Reference our edit controls
    EditControl = Control as EditCustomFileSummary;
    UnifiedFile selectedFile = EditControl.SelectedFile;
    SaveButton = EditControl.FindControl("SaveButton") as ToolButton;

    // Hook into the save event so we can save the input from our custom controls
    SaveButton.Click += OnSaveButtonClick;

    ...
    _tagsControl.Text = selectedFile.Summary.Dictionary["Tags"].ToString();

    ...
    EditControl.Controls.Add(_tagsControl);
}
```

Then you would be able to hook into the save event triggered by the 'Save' control in the summary dialog in order to save your custom field as a dictionary item on the files summary property

```
public void OnSaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a reference to the current file and the summary data
    UnifiedFile selectedFile = EditControl.SelectedFile;

    // Get the tags added
    selectedFile.Summary.Dictionary["Tags"]  = _tagsControl.Text;
}
```

How and what controls you add can of course be derived by whatever method works for your scenario.

Comment: This looks very promising! I'll come back to you when we start on this project